# Rust deserialise and transform some content

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde

I've got a struct:

```rs
struct Embedding {
    values: Vec<f64>,
    original: String,
}
```

which I want to contain some original text `original`, as well as the [embedding](https://huggingface.co/blog/getting-started-with-embeddings) of that text according to OpenAI's [CLIP model](https://github.com/openai/CLIP).

I've got a list of strings in a YAML file (without their embeddings). I want to deserialise that list of strings into a `Vec<Embedding>`, where the `values` member of an `Embedding` should just be the embedded string. I can get the embedding via a function that looks like:

```rs
/// Using a pre-loaded CLIP model, embed some given text into a vector of f64's
fn embed_text(clip_model: &ClipModel, text: &str) -> Result<Vec<f64>> {...}
```

So I need to read the YAML file, deserialise each string, embed each string, and return the `Embedding` struct that has the embedding as well as the original string.

I can't quite figure out how to make this work using the `serde_yaml` or `serde` docs. All the talk of visitors and `deserialise_*` is kinda going over my head. I initially thought `#[serde(deserialize_with = "callback")]` was going to be my savior, but I couldn't get that to work because it only works for a field in a struct, not the struct itself.

I've solved this problem before, in a hacky way, and I'd rather do something cleaner if possible. Before, would have made a `RawEmbedding` and an `Embedding` struct like so:

```rs
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct RawEmbedding {
    original: String,
}

struct Embedding {
    values: Vec<f64>,
    original: String,
}
```

And then I'd manually write a `impl From<RawEmbedding> for Embedding {...}` so that I could use `serde` to deserialise into a `RawEmbedding`, and then `.into()` to convert the `RawEmbedding` into an actual `Embedding`. I'm kinda tired of duplicating all my structs thought, I'm sure there must be a better way that does the conversion logic inside of `serde`'s deserialisation.

Note that I need access to the `ClipModel` (or at least a borrow of it) in order to do the embeddings and loading this model from disk is quite expensive so it's not an option to do again and again for every string that I want to embed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since obtaining the values using the embedding string requires access to the `ClipModel`, we need a way to deserialize while having access to additional context. `serde` has a way to support exactly this, using its [`DeserializeSeed`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.DeserializeSeed.html) trait. The documentation actually calls this out as a specific use case: "If you ever find yourself looking for a way to pass data into a Deserialize impl, this trait is the way to do it."

While `serde` provides ways to derive its `Deserialize` trait, it does not provide a way to derive its `DeserializeSeed` trait. There has been [discussion about supporting it](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/881) in the past, but as things currently are we need to implement the trait manually. This unfortunately involves a bit of boilerplate.

I will assume, for the sake of the example, that the definition of `ClipModel` is as follows:

```rust
struct ClipModel;
```

`DeserializeSeed` is different than `Deserialize` in that it is not often implemented on the type you are wanting to deserialize into. Instead, it is implemented on a type containing the *context* you want to deserialize with. In our case, that context is a reference to `ClipModel`, so we can use it to call `embed_text` during deserialization. The simplest way to provide that context is to just implement `DeserializeSeed` directly on `&ClipModel`. Naturally, if this doesn't work (perhaps because you don't own the definition of `ClipModel`), you can also wrap `&ClipModel` in a newtype.

```rust
use serde::de::{DeserializeSeed, Deserializer, SeqAccess, Visitor};
use std::{fmt, fmt::Formatter};

impl<'a, 'de> DeserializeSeed<'de> for &'a ClipModel {
    type Value = Vec<Embedding>;

    fn deserialize<D>(self, deserializer: D) -> Result<Self::Value, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct ClipModelVisitor<'a>(&'a ClipModel);

        impl<'a, 'de> Visitor<'de> for ClipModelVisitor<'a> {
            type Value = Vec<Embedding>;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("a sequence of embedded strings")
            }

            fn visit_seq<A>(self, mut seq: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
            where
                A: SeqAccess<'de>,
            {
                let mut result = Vec::new();
                while let Some(text) = seq.next_element::<String>()? {
                    result.push(Embedding {
                        // Unwrap is just for demonstration; handle the error in real code!
                        values: embed_text(self.0, &text).unwrap(),
                        original: text,
                    })
                }
                Ok(result)
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_seq(ClipModelVisitor(self))
    }
}
```

If this looks unfamiliar or confusing, I recommend familiarizing yourself with `serde` deserialization in general by reading ["Implementing Deserialize"](https://serde.rs/impl-deserialize.html). The main differences here are:

- `DeserializeSeed` requires you to define a `Value` associated type to indicate the return type of the deserialization. In our case, we declare that we will return a `Vec<Embedding>`.
- We must provide our context type (`&ClipModel`) to our `Visitor` helper struct, so it can be used when accessing each deserialized string.

We can verify that this implementation works by providing a simple implementation of `embed_text` and a simple `yaml` input:

```rust
// Not sure what the error type is here, since it's not provided in the code included with your question.
fn embed_text(clip_model: &ClipModel, text: &str) -> Result<Vec<f64>, ()> {
    Ok(match text {
        "foo" => vec![0.1],
        "bar" => vec![1.2],
        _ => Vec::new(),
    })
}

fn main() {
    let clip_model = ClipModel;

    let result = clip_model.deserialize(serde_yaml::Deserializer::from_str("- foo\n- bar\n"));
    dbg!(result);
}
```

This will output something similar to the following:

```
[src\main.rs:63] result = Ok(
    [
        Embedding {
            values: [
                0.1,
            ],
            original: "foo",
        },
        Embedding {
            values: [
                1.2,
            ],
            original: "bar",
        },
    ],
)
```

You can run the above code at this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=806a17326b6905e0757d27131a5eda8c).

This is the intended solution provided by the `serde` framework for what you are attempting to do. Hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

Why are you deriving a `RawEmbedding` in the first place?

Deserialize the input to a `Vec<String>` then convert from that to an `Embedding`?

Serde does not really have support for additional context, so to make your `ClipModel` available to deserialization you'd need to either implement a `Deserializer` which carries it as local state, or store it as some sort of global so it's available from your conversion functions.

If you go through the raw data you can just

```
....into_iter().map(|s| Embedding {
    values: embed_text(clip, &s).unwrap(),
    original: s
}).collect()
```

or something like that.

Comment: "or something like that" Could you give a MWE? I'm struggling to get the details to work, so leaving the details up to me to figure out won't really work.

Comment: > "Why are you deriving a RawEmbedding in the first place?"
I'm not? I said that the RawEmbedding thing was what I had done in the past but I don't want to do anymore, because it's a bad solution

Comment: This feels like quite a low effort answer IMO, it doesn't give the specifics to answer my question